# How to reliably write and restore partitioned data

Tags: apache-spark

I am looking for a way to write and restore partitioned dataset. For the purpose of this question I can accept both partitioned `RDD`:

```
val partitioner: org.apache.spark.Partitioner = ???
rdd.partitionBy(partitioner)
```

and `Dataset[Row]` / `Dataframe`:

```
df.repartition($"someColumn")
```

The goal is to avoid shuffle when data is restored. For example:

```
spark.range(n).withColumn("foo", lit(1))
  .repartition(m, $"id")
  .write
  .partitionBy("id")
  .parquet(path)
```

shouldn't require shuffle for:

```
spark.read.parquet(path).repartition(m, $"id")
```

I thought about writing partitioned `Dataset` to Parquet but I believe that Spark doesn't use this information.

I can work only with disk storage not a database or data grid.

Answer (score 3):

It might be achieved by bucketBy in dataframe/dataset api probably, but there is a catch - directly saving to parquet won't work, only saveAsTable works.

```java
Dataset<Row> parquet =...;
parquet.write()
  .bucketBy(1000, "col1", "col2")
  .partitionBy("col3")
  .saveAsTable("tableName");

sparkSession.read().table("tableName");
```

Another apporach for spark core is to use custom RDD, e.g see https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/4449 - i.e. after reading hdfs rdd you kind of setup partitioner back, but it a bit hacky and not supported natively(so it need to be adjusted for every spark version)

Comment: @LosInOverflow, so it's not works for you? you don't agree?

Comment: I have to be honest it doesn't :( I still see a shuffle in the plan. RDD solution looks interesting but way to hacky... But it is the only answer so you're lucky today :)

Comment: @LostInOverflow, can you post how you've verified it?

Comment: `spark.range(10000).withColumn("foo", lit(1)).repartition(100, $"id").write.bucketBy(100, "id").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("foo"); spark.read.table("foo").repartition(100, $"id").explain`

Comment: I think you might want to check with 2 tables bucketed by same way and then joining them. I think repartition will shuffle without any notice of bucketing.
Another catch - you are testing withing same spark context, while usually you'll load table in another session(since job runs once per day) to have this work one must use hive support with persistent metastore support(default is in memory and lives only as jvm lives)

Comment: sparkSession.range(10000).withColumnRenamed("id", "id1").withColumn("foo", lit(1)).repartition(100, col("id1")).write().bucketBy(100, "id1").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("foo"); 
sparkSession.range(10000).withColumnRenamed("id", "id2").withColumn("foo", lit(1)).repartition(100, col("id2")).write().bucketBy(100, "id2").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("doo"); 
Dataset<Row> a = sparkSession.table("foo");
Dataset<Row> b = sparkSession.table("doo");
a.join(b, a.col("id1").equalTo(b.col("id2"))).select("id1", "id2").write().mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("abJoin");